# Google Sheets: change the value of a specific cell automatically if a change is made on another sheet being called

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to change the value of a specific cell automatically if a change is made on another sheet being called? I just want to make a "change log" and have the cell display YES or NO depending on the changes made on the called sheet in the past 24 hours.

- YES - there's changes made in the past 24hrs on the called sheet
- NO - no changes made in the past 24hrs on the called sheet

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Also edit the question to make clear why the included tags are relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) In particular look at the onEdit.  Here's the link to the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Here's a potential solution:

This function will track the changes made in the Sheets in the shts array.  I usedd an install onedit trigger.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const name=e.range.getSheet().getName();
  const shts=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];  
  const idx=shts.indexOf(name);
  if(idx!=-1) {
    const ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"ddMMyy HH:mm:ss")
    const sh=e.source.getSheetByName('Changes');
    if(e.range.columnStart==e.range.columnEnd && e.range.rowStart==e.range.rowEnd) {
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5).setValues([[e.value,e.oldValue,ts,name,e.range.getA1Notation()]]);
    }else{
      const s=e.range.getValues().flat().join(',');
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5).setValues([[undefined,s,ts,name,e.range.getA1Notation()]]);
    }
    sh.getRange(2,2).offset(0,idx).setValue('YES');
  }
}
```

This function will reset the changes sheet where all changes are recording as shown in the image below:

```
function resetChanges() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Changes');
  sh.getRange(2,2,1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow()-4,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
}
```

image:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. But I'm not a programmer :(

Comment: This is the actual answer, your requirements need the use of triggers in the sheets. If you are not a programmer I don't see this being made with just UI and sheets functions. I would recommend you to try to learn [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) or hire someone to do it for you.